# How to implement the condition in reactjs request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have request like this previously:

```
let data = {

      chartLibraryType : this.state.chartCategory == 'highChart'? "HIGH_CHARTS" : "C3",

    };
```

Now I need to implement with 3. Along with highcharts and c3 I need to pass d3 also.

```
let data = {

      chartLibraryType : if(this.state.chartCategory == 'highChart'){
                            "HIGH_CHARTS"
                        }else if(this.state.chartCategory == 'c3Chart'){
                            "C3"
                        }else if(this.state.chartCategory == 'D3Chart'){
                            "D3"
                            },

    };
```

Is this the way to implement when we have more than 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can create a `dictionary`.

```
let dictionary={
   "highChart" : "HIGH_CHARTS",
   "c3Chart" : "C3",
   "D3Chart" : "D3"
}
```

Then you have to pass **state** as a key for **dictionary** using `bracket` notation.

```
let data = {
  chartLibraryType : dictionary[this.state.chartCategory]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch like si :

```
let data = { chartLibraryType: '' }

switch (this.state.chartCategory) {
  case 'highChart':
    data.chartLibraryType = 'HIGH_CHARTS'
    break
  case 'c3Chart':
    data.chartLibraryType = 'C3'
    break
  case 'D3Chart':
    data.chartLibraryType = 'D3'
    break
  // Add as much `case` as you wish without forgetting the break clause
  // If you'd like to fallback to a default value
  default:
    break
}
```

I also invite you to take a look at this great collection of books ["You don't know JS"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)